# Xamarin android references not found

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to open an existing xamarin project for android, and all the references have exclamation marks.

The properties of the project are to compile for Android 9.0 sdk and this is set to automatically download and install.

I get hundreds of errors and even get 'The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found'

I already looked around on the internet and the only accepted solution was to reinstall windows/visual studio.
Surely this cannot be right.

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: Rebuild your project. I experience that anytime I start a new project.

Comment: Hi, already tried that. Clean and rebuilt

Comment: Can you do some detective work first? Pick a reference that isn't resolving, look at its properties to see what file/path it's referencing, then locate the where that file actually *is* on the file system, and take it from there. You might find that you can simply edit your project-reference paths using a global search/replace... At least it's a start.

Comment: Try to restore your nuget packages or uninstall/install the specific package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies!

Finally as Jack Hua suggested I had to use update-package-reinstall to reinstall all the packages.

One package however blocked this operation, and I had to choose a different TargetFrameworkProfile in the project settings.

Comment: You can mark this answer later which will help more people with same problem:).